# How to make redirect?

Tags: django

How to redirect from http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/signin/ to http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/ with HttpResponseRedirect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you've set up your urls.py file correctly, it should just be a case of:

```
  HttpResponseRedirect('/profile')
```

The above should obviously go in the appropriate view as, for example:

```
def signin(request):
    ...
    ... # perform whatever logic
    HttpResponseRedirect('/profile') # redirect to 'profile'
```